# Build a graph as a subset of another, larger, graph [iGraph, Python]

Tags: python, igraph

I need to compute the density of a subgraph made of vertices belonging to the same attribute "group".

ie., let g be an iGraph graph,

```
g.vs.select(group = 1)
```

gives me an object with all vertices belonging to group 1

Is there any way to compute density on the graph which is formed by these vertices and the connections between them?

In a fashion similar to this maybe?

```
g2.vs(g2.vs.select(group = i)).density()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
g.vs.select(group=1).subgraph().density()
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tamàa, this seems to works great. Your help is always very appreciated...